# ADFS configuration for SharePoint 2016 new web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, web-application, adfs

I have successfully configured for one web application. While adding the second web application using PowerShell script I have given wrong urn and now when I try to update the urn in SharePoint it throws the error

> Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "An item with the same key has already been added.

The script which I used to update the second web application is below:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
 
 $sts = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer | where {$_.Name -eq "ADFS"}

 $uri = new-object System.Uri("https://contoso.com/")
 
 $sts.ProviderRealms.Add($uri, "urn:sharepoint:MyNewWebApplicationURL")
 
 $sts.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the existing URI (which you added incorrectly).

```
$sts.ProviderRealms.Remove($uri)

$sts.Update()
```

Now try to re add it with proper uri.

Comment: HI Waqas thank you , it wokred.  how can I renew the token signing cert on SharePoint side , as I have two different tokenissuers in my environment. How to update without affecting the other one , Can you let me know. sorry for the different question here